# how to sort an array by highest value in desc order?

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, foreach, bubble-sort

I have arrays that look like:

```
$array['keyword1'] = 20;
$array['keyword4'] = 1;
$array['keywordsda'] = 33;
```

.....about 1k of these.

How would I sort them by the value desc?

```
$array['keywordsda'] = 33;
$array['keyword1'] = 20;
$array['keyword4'] = 1;
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: i'l vote it down as lack of research.

Comment: My thought would be I would search any relevant manual for 'sort'. The PHP manual seems a very likely candidate for this.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the function [arsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php) to do so...

> This function sorts an array such that array indices maintain their
>   correlation with the array elements they are associated with.
>
> This is used mainly when sorting associative arrays where the actual
>   element order is significant.

It will order your array in reverse order (higher to lower) maintainning your indexes.

Answer (score 4):

look for functions in manual: sort, array_reverse

```
sort($your_array, SORT_NUMERIC);
$your_array = array_reverse($your_array, true);
```

If you want to preserve keys send true as second parameter of array_reverse, if not, then you can omit it.

Answer (score 3):

[`rsort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rsort.php) sorts an array in reverse order.  You could use `rsort($array, SORT_NUMERIC)`, but I think it's likely to work the same without the second argument.